# Search a text file for specific word if found copy the entire line to new file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to search the string `failed` in a text file and if found copy the entire line to another file.

Contends of test.txt:

```
: \Hardware\Disk Enclosure 27              diskslot1 failed  
: \Hardware\Disk Enclosure 27              diskslot2 normal  
: \Hardware\Disk Enclosure 27              diskslot3 normal 
: \Hardware\Disk Enclosure 27              diskslot4 normal
```

Please help on the script

Comment: The `Select-String` cmdlet is made to do things like this. Run `Get-Help Select-String` and you'll read, among other things: "By default, Select-String finds the first match in each line and, for each match, it displays the file name, line number, and all text in the line containing the match."

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
select-string -path "D:\Textfile.txt" -Pattern "Text" | select line | out-file d:\outputfile.txt -append
```

Edit for Output without Line

```
$Output = select-string -path "d:\textfile.txt" -pattern "Text". 
$Output.line | out-file d:\outputfile.txt -append
```

Comment: Its working as i expected.. But there is entry "Line" in the file. Is it possible append to file without word "Line"

Comment: No Problem. If you're satisfied, please mark the thread as solved

Answer (score 0):

This script prints every line containing "myword":

```
f = open('file.txt')
for line in f:
       if "myword" in f:
              print (line)
else: print(a)

f.close()
```