# Automatically Create Indexes in Different Filegroup, edit Publish Profile Script

Tags: sql-server, regex, powershell, sql-server-2016, powershell-4.0

I need a way to automatically move clustered indexes into one filegroup : ClusteredFilegroup, and all nonclustered indexes to a different filegroup NonClusteredFilegroup upon DDL creation . We have sql publish profile which creates similar script below every weekly deployment. How do I utilize powershell to conduct this?

I would like to have powershell add words 
`ON [ClusteredFilegroup]` after every table creation

or `ON [NonClusteredFilegroup]` for every nonclustered index.

Powershell should be able to read original script (testscript.sql), and run text edits on it.

**Original Script:**

```
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dim_Product] (
    [DimProductId]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductName]         VARCHAR(64)    NOT NULL,
    [ProductDescription]  VARCHAR(64)    NOT NULL,
    [BeginDate]           DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [EndDate]             DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DimProductId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DimProductId] ASC)
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCX_Product_ProductName]
    ON [dbo].[Dim_Product]([ProductName] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCX_Product_BeginDate]
    ON [dbo].[Dim_Product]([BeginDate] ASC);   


GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dim_Customer] (
    [DimCustomertId]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerName]         VARCHAR(64)    NOT NULL,
    [CustomerDescription]  VARCHAR(64)    NOT NULL,
    [BeginDate]           DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    [EndDate]             DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DimCustomerId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DimCustomerId] ASC)
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCX_Customer_CustomerName]
    ON [dbo].[Dim_Customer]([CustomerName] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCX_Customer_BeginDate]
    ON [dbo].[Dim_Customer]([BeginDate] ASC);
```

**Goal:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dim_Product] (
     [DimProductId]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [ProductName]         VARCHAR(64)   NOT NULL,
     [ProductDescription]  VARCHAR(64)   NOT NULL,
     [BeginDate]           DATETIME      NOT NULL,
     [EndDate]             DATETIME      NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_DimProductId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DimProductId] ASC)
    ) ON [ClusteredFilegroup];

    GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCX_Product_ProductName]
     ON [dbo].[Dim_Product]([ProductName] ASC) ON [NonClusteredFilegroup];
```

I am trying to research these scripts:

[Add text to every line in text file using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952535/add-text-to-every-line-in-text-file-using-powershell)

[Search a text file for specific word if found copy the entire line to new file in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988103/search-a-text-file-for-specific-word-if-found-copy-the-entire-line-to-new-file-i)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229380/automatically-have-nonclustered-indexes-in-a-different-filegroup/229382#229382

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$sql = Get-Content .\org.sql -Raw
$sql = $sql -replace '(?smi)(CREATE TABLE (.*?))\);','$1 ) ON [ClusteredFilegroup];'
$sql = $sql -replace '(?smi)(CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX (.*?))\);','$1) ON [NonClusteredFilegroup];'
$sql | Set-Content -Path .\new.sql
```

`(?smi)` tells the replace statement to match multiple lines (m) and include new-lines (s) and ignore case (i).
`(.*?)` includes anything including newlines (hence the `(?smi)`), but not greedy (`?`).

Comment: Yes, the line `$sql = Get-Content .\org.sql -Raw` reads a SQL file. Replace `.\org.sql` with a filename and/or path to your `.sql` file, for instance: `$sql = Get-Content d:\Exports\testscript.sql -Raw`

This helped a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12573413/1846184
And this: https://regex101.com/r/rkm4bT/1
And you may upvote the answer if you're happy with it.